# Wasserstein distance between rotated conditional distributions

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we have a probability distribution $\rho$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $ E \subset \operatorname{supp}(\rho) $, and $R_\theta$ a rotation of angle $\theta$ such that $ R_\theta E \subset \operatorname{supp}(\rho) $. Let $ \rho(x \mid x \in E) $ be the conditional distribution on $E$.

Is it true that
$$
W_1(\rho(x \mid x \in E),\rho(x \mid x \in R_\theta E)) \lesssim \operatorname{diam}(\operatorname{supp}(\rho)) \cdot \theta \qquad ?
$$

I think this is true at least if $\rho$ is rotational invariant, but I was wondering if it can be generalized.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can expect the good factor of $\epsilon$ in general.  Consider $E 
= [-1, 1] \times [-\epsilon, \epsilon]$ and $\rho$ the uniform distribution on $E$.  Note the diameter is independent of $\epsilon$. For any $\theta$, we can send $\epsilon$ to zero and the distribution of the rotated measure gets all in a little region around the origin (think of the intersection of a line and a rotated line).  This should show we can make the LHS at least [something] independent of $\theta$.

Comment: "good factor of $\epsilon$" should read "good factor of $\theta$".

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not sure to follow, though. In your example, $\operatorname{supp}(\rho)=E$, right? If so, $R_\theta E$ is not contained in $\operatorname{supp}(\rho)$.

Comment: Ah, I missed that assumption :)  You're right.

Comment: What if we take the same $E$, but we take $\rho$ to be $(1-\delta)$ times the uniform distribution on $E$, plus $\delta$ times the uniform distribution on the circle of radius 2?  

Now for fixed $\epsilon$ and $\theta$ if you send $\delta$ to zero the mass of the rotated-conditional-distribution should concentrate in the intersection of $E$ and $R_\theta E$.  So you may be able to get back to my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you, good point! So, since the mass is concentrating in the middle, you may have to pay $\operatorname{diam}(\operatorname{supp}(\rho))$ to spread it back along $E$. If this gives a lower bound on $W_1$, then your counterexample works. Still, there seems to be another natural action to transport $ \rho(x \mid x \in R_\theta E) $ onto $ \rho(x \mid x \in E) $, which is the rotation $R_\theta$ itself... I am still confused... :)

Comment: Tim Carson's counterexample seems to work well. $\rho(x | x \in R_\theta E)$ is basically the point mass at 0, so the rotation $R_\theta$ is not a valid transport. Note that $\rho(x | x \in R_\theta E)$ is very different from the pushforward $\rho(x | x \in E) \circ R_{\theta}^{-1}$.